# Customizing Stream React Chat Components styles

Tags: getstream-io

I'm considering using Stream Chat in my React app, but would like to implement a few of my own customizations to the React Components' styles.

I see [the Sass source code on Github](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react/tree/master/src/styles), which looks approachable, and seems that it would be fairly easy to tweak. However, these source files aren't included in the published `stream-chat-react` npm package; only the pre-compiled `index.css` stylesheet is distributed.

I would like to avoid writing ad-hoc CSS rules to override the provided styles. Is there a recommended way of achieving some UI customizations, ideally working with Stream's source Sass files?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to approach this is to get the source files from the repository and building the css yourself. I have added some scripts and a [section in the README](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react#customizing-styles) on how to do this easily.